# didSelectViewController method not being called (with storyboard)

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I have 2 versions of a tabbed ios5 application, one created using a storyboard and one using xib files.  The storyboard version does not call the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `didSelectViewController` (the xib version does). Something is (I think) missing from the storyboard, but I don't know what. Another way of framing the question might be — how can I refer to the `UITabBarController` object instantiated by the storyboard?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The tab bar controller delegate is set:

In AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}
```

Then later in AppDelegate.m, the delegate method is:

```
- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Got Here");
}
```

The NSLog output never appears. The problem seems to me to be that I am not correctly referencing the tab bar controller object which has been instantiated by the storyboard.
How do I do that?

Comment: Have you set the delegate? Can you show some code?

Comment: The tab bar delegate is set in AppDelegate.h:

Comment: Dud u find out about this I have the same problem.

Comment: Got it work? Found the answer?

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue.

If you're not using storyboards, setting the `UITabBarController` delegate in the `AppDelegate` is the way to go. However, with `Storyboards`, the `AppDelegate` has no idea where the `tabBarController` is on startup. You'd think by `subclassing` the `tabBarController` and adding the delegate method:

```
(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
   didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

}
```

... would be enough. But, it's irritatingly not.

I needed to know when a user had pressed a tab button. I needed to know this more that I needed to know that the viewController's "`- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {}`
" method had been run.

I decided to make my `UITabBarController` a delegate of itself. This seemed silly to me but I did the following...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlumbsTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end
```

And then, in my `viewDidLoad` method, wrote the following:

```
[self setDelegate:self];
```

Which enabled my tab bar delegate methods to run.

Crazy or what?

Ok - I'm editing this answer now, as even though the above is all correct, where a `navigationController` is being used, selected with each `tabBarButton` touched, the `didSelectViewController` delegate method will, when you try to `NSLog(@"%@", viewController);` only show you that you have selected the `UINavigationController` class?

So, the total solution, just to add more complexity, is to subclass the `UINavigationController` for each `viewController` that you want to monitor, (do something) when the `tabBarbutton` has been touched.

It works for me anyhow. And, if anyone can nit-pick through the above dribble, they might find an aspect that's useful - and that's enough for me - seeing as I find this site utterly useful too.

Comment: In my case, this answer worked only if the `didSelectViewController` method was also in the `UITabBarController` file rather than the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 6):

Put `[self setDelegate:self];` in your `ViewDidLoad` or somewhere where the object get's initialized

Comment: you mean I have to add above method in my first ViewController of first NavigationController of TabBarController? can you please elaborate your solution.